# Is there a server-level static variable in PHP?

Tags: php, scope, declaration

My website (served by PHP) uses some values, which are expensive to calculate (and the calculation is deterministic), therefore I'd like to cache the result at the first request. Then I could use this function:

```
function MyValue($valueID) {
  if (!isset($myValueCache[$valueID])) {
    $myValueCache[$valueID] = ... // The long and expensive calculation.
  }
  return $myValueCache[$valueID];
}
```

The question is, how to declare `$myValueCache` to preserve its value **between different calls of the script**? I'd call it *"server-level static variable"* or something like. A simple `static` variable is not the desired solution. http://www.elated.com/articles/php-variable-scope-all-you-need-to-know/ writes: "Once the script exits, a static variable gets destroyed, just like local and global variables do." I'd like to preserve the value until I explicitly `unset` it. Thanks :)

PS. "expensive" means database access for example. Calculating and hard-coding the result is not possible at development time.

Comment: If user specific then stuff it in a session, if not save it in a DB field since you already have a DB.  Not expensive `SELECT value FROM cache WHERE id=$valueID`

Comment: Well, after a long silence, I think the final answer is: "There is no such variable declaration in PHP." (But I'm not sure, that is why I've asked it.) Thanks for the recommended workarounds. The in-memory database with @AbraCadaver's explanation might be a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using of any in-memory database, like Redis or Memcached. You can also try to cache values in files, but it will be slower than in-memory databases.

Comment: Thanks, but the DBMS is not my choice, and this workaround is not really an answer to the question. We can't move the complete database to memory just for this issue.

Comment: You store that variable in the memory cache not the database.

Comment: Believe me, for caching purposes you can't find anything better than in-memory storage. It's only called database, because it looks similar, but in fact it has nothing to do with classic DBMS.